# Как в DataGridView  сделать поле с кнопкой

Tags: c#, gridview, visual-studio

У меня есть таблица "Блоки" со списком, и связующая таблица "Подшихт. Партия" с перечислением по ключу. Мне нужно чтобы в одной таблице были списки "Блоков" и "Партия" через пробел(это я собственно смог). Но как мне сделать в одном поле еще и кнопку?
Для наглядности приложу скриншот примерно того как я это вижу. Есть у вас рекомендации по этому поводу ?
[link text](http://s019.radikal.ru/i640/1311/40/0f481fb0f5af.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не совсем то, мне нужно чтобы в поле
> было и отображение данных и кнопка
> сразу (посмотри картинку которую я
> выложил). Если что таблица только для
> просмотра редактировать и добавлять
> нельзя.

Если это WinForms, то Вам надо писать кастомный тип колонки. [По ссылке](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.110).aspx) пример для `DateTimePicker`, но суть от этого не меняется (хотя проще сделать как Вам посоветовал [[@Freezze](/users/2056/freezze)](/users/2056/freezze) - добавить дополнительную колонку с кнопкой).

Если же это WPF, то все еще проще: создаете [DataGridTemplateColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx) и уже в него укладываете все что душе угодно.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотри тип значения колонки.
Скорее всего тебе нужен: DataGridViewButtonColumn
И посмотри [здесь](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bxt3k60s(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Не совсем то, мне нужно чтобы в поле было и отображение данных и кнопка сразу (посмотри картинку которую я выложил). Если что таблица только для просмотра редактировать и добавлять нельзя.

Comment: А добавить еще одну колонку с кнопкой можно? Как вариант можно обработать нажатие на ячейку.